# Augury tab does not show on chrome devtools

Tags: angular, google-chrome, augury

I have a version of google chrome is 108.0.5359.125 (Build oficial) (64 bits) and I've installed Augury from the Chrome web store

[image]

[image]

Any idea of how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/rangle/augury/issues/1507), **Angular DevTools** replaced **Augury** and there is no Augury in the chrome web store, I made a mistake because Augury that I've installed is not the correct chrome extension.